# Bind mouse key to continuously send clicks

Tags: mouse

Question is in the title. I have a mouse with extra buttons and would like to bind the button so that it sends continous left clicks when I hold it down.

Comment: Like this perhaps? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173315/how-to-simulate-multiple-mouse-clicks-while-holding-the-mouse-button

Comment: Something like that but the solution doesn't work in the way that I need.

Comment: First app that came to mind: [Better Touch Tool](https://www.boastr.net/). I'm pretty sure it can do it...

Answer (score 1):

What mouse brand? Some mouse brands provide macro software to individuals for games mostly.

Logitech Macro Software(G-SERIES ONLY):

http://support.logitech.com/en_gb/software/lgs

Razer Macro Software:

https://www.razerzone.com/synapse

The ones I've used are those and they allow you if you have one of their products at bind, change and macro at ease.

THERE IS ALSO KEYBOARD MAESTRO, don't need any exclusive product(never used this before, use at your own risk):

https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/

Comment: Cheap nonsense brand. I don't want to pay for keyboard maestro.

Comment: If you do have a razer or logitech keyboard (g-series) you could rebind the macro keys to spam mouse1 clicks, but if you're really determined to macro on your mac you could use wine. Wine will open windows software on your mac, you could try and open AHK(Auto Hot Key) on your mac however I don't know how much functionality it'd have...